# stripe create account and charge a card

Tags: php, database, stripe-payments, credit-card, stripe-connect

Trying to work with Stripe to create an account, charge a card, and sign up for a subscription which will start 15-30 days later.

What I want to do is:

1) Collect up front the use infomation (email, address, first/last name, card info, etc) which will be added a customer on stripe and in my database.

2) Do the initial charge (not the subscription charge) and if pass will create the account on both stipe and my database.

3) Make sure I have Stipe's info for the customer in my database to charge cade at later date. Have not decided if I will run a cron to to the monthly charge or have Stripe to do it.

4) If Payment for subscriptions ends (by bad credit card monthly charge or other reason), limit what the person sees when they login. This is why I was thinking of having a cron run and if it is marked as need payment, do the limited view.

Thanks for help and advice in advance!

Comment: Hire a developer, SO is not a code writing service. Please, take the [tour]. Alternatively, you can show us your existing code and be specific about issues you are facing and we can assist your to solve the problem.

Comment: Are we to design, develop and implement it for you? Where is your code?

Comment: No, Getting advice and first time to use Stipe.  I put the steps just as a reference to show my plan. Just trying to get a better grasp of stripe...

Answer (score 0):

So apparently I offended a couple of people. I also forgot to mentioned that I was trying do do it with AJAX which was my main problem I was trying to work out.

I have actually found some related links, finally, that seems to have pointed me into the right direction that I was looking for. Which mainly what I wanted.

Below are the links that has helped me so far. Hopes they help anyone looking for the same thing.

https://youtu.be/EildM6OMcoQ

Not sure why this one finally showed up on my search? Guess did not phase my search correctly...

[Make a Stripe payment with Jquery AJAX? (Javascript ONLY)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38819502/make-a-stripe-payment-with-jquery-ajax-javascript-only)

There is one or two more link, but I will have to find them. I will add them once they are found....

Here is my test scripts, mainly for checking on passing the token... 
Will need to see about making it work with STRIPE 
V3 API...

Form.php

```
   <?php session_start(); ?>
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
   <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
   <title>Stripe Getting Started Form</title>

   <!-- The required Stripe lib -->
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>

   <!-- jQuery is used only for this example; it isn't required to use Stripe -->
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript">
   // This identifies your website in the createToken call below
   Stripe.setPublishableKey('__YOUR__PUBLIC__HERE__);

   var stripeResponseHandler = function(status, response) {
   var $form = $('#payment-form');

   if (response.error) {
   // Show the errors on the form
   $form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
   $form.find('button').prop('disabled', false);
   } else {
   // token contains id, last4, and card type
   var token = response.id;
   // Insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
   $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(token));
   // and re-submit
   //$form.get(0).submit();

   // Serialize the form
   var data=$('#payment-form').serialize(); 

   // Send form to server with POST method
   $(function() {
       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "./testphp.php",
           data: data,
           success: function(returndata){
               $form.find('button').prop('disabled', false);
               $('.payment-errors').text(returndata);
           }
       });
   });

   // Prevent page from refreshing
   return false;

   }
   };

   // ONCLICK RESPONSE 
   jQuery(function($) {
   $('#thebutton').on('click', function(e) {
       var $form = $('#payment-form');

       // Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
       $form.find('button').prop('disabled', true);

       Stripe.card.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);

       // Prevent the form from submitting with the default action
       return false;
       });
   });
   </script>

   </head>
   <body>

   <?php 
   //$_SESSION['token'] = "12345";
   echo $_SESSION['token']; // will only show if page is reloaded
                            // will not be the same as new token
                            // used to check against after submit
   ?>

   <h1>Charge $10 with Stripe</h1>

   <form action="" method="POST" id="payment-form">
   <span class="payment-errors"></span>

   <div class="form-row">
   <label>
   <span>Card Number</span>

   <input type="text" size="20" data-stripe="number" value="424242424242424"/>

   </label>
   </div>

   <div class="form-row">
   <label>
   <span>CVC</span>
   <input type="text" size="4" data-stripe="cvc" value="424" />
   </label>
   </div>

   <div class="form-row">
   <label>
   <span>Expiration (MM/YYYY)</span>
   <input type="text" size="2" data-stripe="exp-month" value="01"/>
   </label>
   <span> / </span>
   <input type="text" size="4" data-stripe="exp-year" value="2019"/>
   </div>

   <button type="submit" id="thebutton">Submit Payment</button>
   </form>
   </body>
   </html>
```

testphp.php

```
<?php
    // Start the session
    session_start();

    // Store the received token string in a session variable
    if($_POST){
        $_SESSION['token']=$_POST['stripeToken'];
    }
    echo $_POST['stripeToken'];
    echo "\n";
    print_r($_SESSION);
?>
```

There are a lot of other things I am going to have to work out, but this mainly was mainly the direction I was looking advice on....