# Is it possible to do payment through stripe using JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, stripe-payments

I'm trying to make payment through stripe in hubspot using jquery or javascript 
My Code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>

<form id="myForm" action="" method="POST">
  <input type="text" id="amountInDollars" />
  <input type="hidden" id="stripeToken" name="stripeToken" />
  <input type="hidden" id="stripeEmail" name="stripeEmail" />
  <input type="hidden" id="amountInCents" name="amountInCents" />
</form>

<input type="button" id="customButton" value="Pay">

<script>
var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
  key: 'pk_test_******************',
  image: 'https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png',
  token: function(token) {
    $("#stripeToken").val(token.id);
    $("#stripeEmail").val(token.email);
    $("#amountInCents").val(Math.floor($("#amountInDollars").val() * 100));
    $("#myForm").submit();
  }
});

$('#customButton').on('click', function(e) {
  var amountInCents = Math.floor($("#amountInDollars").val() * 100);
  var displayAmount = parseFloat(Math.floor($("#amountInDollars").val() * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
  // Open Checkout with further options
  handler.open({
    name: 'p1',
    description: 'Custom amount ($' + displayAmount + ')',
    amount: amountInCents,
  });
  e.preventDefault();
});

// Close Checkout on page navigation
$(window).on('popstate', function() {
  handler.close();
});

</script>
```

So my question here, Is it possible to implement payment module of stripe using javascript or jquery ?? if yes then what am i doing wrong, i cant figure it out.
my code is working with no error but the test data not showing on stripe account.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make a Stripe payment with Jquery AJAX? (Javascript ONLY)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38819502/make-a-stripe-payment-with-jquery-ajax-javascript-only)

Comment: @taintedzodiac I viewed the question you mentioned in the comment, the problem here is my code is working with no error but the test data not showing on stripe account.

Answer (score 1):

Of course is possible to do that, you can use the [client-only checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/client_only), the guide is pretty straightforward :) you can add it to your page by creating the form in the Stripe dashboard

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to stripe provide JavaScript examples as well you can follow the following link https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js